# Multi application obfuscation technique issue

Tags: java, maven, proguard, obfuscation

I've structured my software in a 'core/base application' + 'addon/plugin' approach, while my core is obfuscated to the public, the addons also need to be obfuscated while also match its core mappings.

The core is obfuscated with Proguard using this Maven plugin:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <injar>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</injar>
                            <proguardVersion>5.2</proguardVersion>
                            <options>
                                <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                                <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                                <option>-dontshrink</option>
                                <option>-dontnote</option>
                                <option>-dontwarn</option> <!-- added option to ignore com.sun missing classes -->
                                <option>-keep class class.to.main.Here</option>
                            </options>
                            <libs>
                                <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                            </libs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And it works fine, I'm able to obfuscate both programs, just they don't share each others mappings.

The issue is getting the addon programs to obfuscate using the libraries obfuscation mappings but instead its just leaving the core library method calls unobfuscated which in the runtime will definitely fail.

The goal is to have it so the core application is obfuscated while not inhibiting programmers working on this application from being able to code addons in an unobfuscated environment that gets obfuscated later after the addon is made.

I've foraged the internet for examples but I cannot find one that talks about this setup, not sure if its a common one or my keywords were terrible.